# Filling memory slots to allow dual channel

Tags: memory-management

I have [Gigabyte P55](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128425) motherboard and an [Intel i7-860](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115214) cpu running Windows 7-64Bit.

I have 2 sticks of 1GB RAM and one stick of 2GB RAM.

With four dual-channel memory slots on the motherboard, what is the best physical configuration of my memory sticks?

Does putting the two 1GB sticks in slots #1 & #3 perform better than putting the 2GB stick in #1?

Will there be any noticeable difference?

Comment: In order for dual channel to work you need to have the same size sticks. So having 2 1GB and 1 @GB will not allow dual channel, just leave them in what ever configuration they are in now. Get your self a dual channel kit, or just buy 2 2gb sticks of the same speed RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for dual channel to work you need to have the same size sticks. So having 2 1GB and 1 @GB will not allow dual channel, just leave them in what ever configuration they are in now. Get your self a dual channel kit, or just buy 2 2gb sticks of the same speed RAM. – Kyle 15 hours ago

Comment: Did you just copy Kyle's comment and answer it like it was your own?

Comment: @Troggy Yeah, but he also included `Kyle – 15 hours ago`. :)